# Scroll Horizontal en Android Canvas

Tags: java, android

Estoy trabajando con la clase Canvas y tengo varios problemas.

Tengo una clase llamada Workbench que extiende la clase View para usarlo como canvas.

En el canvas hay X cuadrados y puedo arrastrarlos por la pantalla. Le he añadido la funcion para que se pueda hacer como un scroll horizontal, que en realidad lo que hace es aumentar o disminuir la coordenada del ejeX de cada objeto en el canvas, y es aqui donde falla. Cuando hago un scroll de izquierda a derecha todos los objetos se desplazan bien y siguen la misma relacion de posicion que tenian, pero cuando lo hago de derecha a izquierda y los objetos llegan al limite de la pantalla no se desplazan.

Si lo hago rapido si que sobrepasan el limite pero si se hace despacio permanecen en el limite y se van juntando todos.

Clase Workbench:

```
public class Workbench extends View {
    public Point puntoMedio;
    public int lastPosX =0;
    List<Objeto> objetoList = new ArrayList<Objeto>();
    int seleccionado = 0;
    public Workbench(Context context) {
        super(context);
        puntoMedio = new Point(0,0);
        for(int i=0;i<5;i++){
            Objeto o = new Objeto();
            o.coordenada.set(10,10);
            objetoList.add(o);
        }

    }

    @Override
    protected void onDraw(Canvas c) {
        super.onDraw(c);
        int HEIGHT = c.getHeight(),WIDTH = c.getWidth();

        Paint p = new Paint();
        p.setColor(Color.RED);
        c.drawRect(0,0,WIDTH,HEIGHT,p);
        dibujar(c);
        invalidate();
    }

    private void dibujar(Canvas c){
        int HEIGHT = c.getHeight(),WIDTH = c.getWidth();
        for(Objeto o:objetoList){
            Paint p = new Paint();
            p.setColor(Color.YELLOW);
            //c.drawCircle(o.coordenada.x,o.coordenada.y,30,p);
            c.drawRect(o.coordenada.x,o.coordenada.y,o.coordenada.x+30,o.coordenada.y+30,p);
            //c.drawRect(o.coordenada.x,o.coordenada.y,100,100,p);
        }
    }

    public void onDragEvent(int x,int y) {
        String datos = String.valueOf(x)+","+String.valueOf(y);
        Log.d("Inicio",datos);

        puntoMedio.set(x,y);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent event) {
        String datos = String.valueOf(event.getX())+","+String.valueOf(event.getY());
        puntoMedio.set(((int) event.getX()), ((int) event.getY()));

        seleccionado = obtenerTocado(new Point(((int) event.getX()), ((int) event.getY())));
        //Log.d("Seleccionado",String.valueOf(seleccionado));

        if(seleccionado <= objetoList.size()){
            objetoList.get(seleccionado).coordenada.set(((int) event.getX()), ((int) event.getY()));
        } else {
            // Detectr izq o der
            if(event.getX()-lastPosX>0 & lastPosX!=0){
                //Derecha
                for(Objeto o:objetoList){
                    o.coordenada.x +=event.getX()-lastPosX;
                }

            }else if (lastPosX!=0){
                //Izq
                for(Objeto o:objetoList){
                    o.coordenada.x -= -1*(event.getX()-lastPosX);
                }

            }
            lastPosX = (int)event.getX();
        }
        if (event.getAction() == android.view.MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN) {
            Log.d("TouchTest", "Touch down");
        } else if (event.getAction() == android.view.MotionEvent.ACTION_UP) {
            Log.d("TouchTest", "Touch up");
            lastPosX = 0;
        }
        return super.onTouchEvent(event);
    }
    private int obtenerTocado(Point punto){
        int out = 10;
        Log.d("Seleccionado","Punto tocado:("+punto.x+","+punto.y+")");
        for(int i=0;i<objetoList.size();i++){
            Objeto o = objetoList.get(i);
            Log.d("Seleccionado","Objeto pos: ("+o.coordenada.x+","+o.coordenada.y+")");
            if(punto.x-o.coordenada.x<=o.bounds[2]&punto.x-o.coordenada.x>=o.bounds[0]){
                if(punto.y-o.coordenada.y<=o.bounds[1]){
                    if(punto.y-o.coordenada.y>=o.bounds[3]){
                        return i;
                    }
                }
            }
        }

        return out;
    }

}
```

Metodo onCreate en el MainActivity:

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        final Workbench workbench = new Workbench(this);
        setContentView(workbench);
       workbench.setOnLongClickListener(new View.OnLongClickListener() {
           @Override
           public boolean onLongClick(View view) {
                Log.d("CANV","INICIO");
               workbench.onDragEvent((int)view.getX(),(int)view.getY());
               return false;
           }
       });

    }
```

Clase Objeto:

```
public class Objeto {
    Point coordenada = new Point();
    int bounds[] = {-50,30,50,-30};
}
```

Comment: ¿Podrías incluir la clase `Objeto` para reproducir enteramente el código? Me hago una ligera idea de donde podría estar el problema pero me gustaría reproducirlo por completo antes de dar una posible respuesta.

Comment: @Israel he añadido la clase.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

El problema principal en esto, es la comparación de números flotantes, es un tema que daría una larga explicación, pero en tu caso es innecesario y que no necesitas una precisión completamente exacta.
Con ésto, me refiero a cuando desplazas el cuadrado, mezclas `int` y `float` para hacer tus cálculos. Esa pérdida de precisión, hace que los cuadrados automaticamente vayan hacia la derecha ya que entra en la condicion el if.

Te facilito la clase como me ha quedado:

```
public class Workbench extends View {
public Point puntoMedio;
public float lastPosX = 0;
List<Objeto> objetoList = new ArrayList<Objeto>();
int seleccionado = 0;

public Workbench(Context context) {
    super(context);
    puntoMedio = new Point(0, 0);
    for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
        Objeto o = new Objeto();
        o.coordenada.set(10, 10);
        objetoList.add(o);
    }

}

@Override
protected void onDraw(Canvas c) {
    super.onDraw(c);
    int HEIGHT = c.getHeight(), WIDTH = c.getWidth();

    Paint p = new Paint();
    p.setColor(Color.RED);
    c.drawRect(0, 0, WIDTH, HEIGHT, p);
    dibujar(c);
    invalidate();
}

private void dibujar(Canvas c) {
    int HEIGHT = c.getHeight(), WIDTH = c.getWidth();
    for (Objeto o : objetoList) {
        Paint p = new Paint();
        p.setColor(Color.YELLOW);
        //c.drawCircle(o.coordenada.x,o.coordenada.y,30,p);
        c.drawRect(o.coordenada.x, o.coordenada.y, o.coordenada.x + 30, o.coordenada.y + 30, p);
        //c.drawRect(o.coordenada.x,o.coordenada.y,100,100,p);
    }
}

public void onDragEvent(int x, int y) {
    String datos = String.valueOf(x) + "," + String.valueOf(y);
    Log.d("Inicio", datos);

    puntoMedio.set(x, y);
}

@Override
public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent event) {
    String datos = String.valueOf(event.getX()) + "," + String.valueOf(event.getY());
    puntoMedio.set(((int) event.getX()), ((int) event.getY()));

    seleccionado = obtenerTocado(new Point(((int) event.getX()), ((int) event.getY())));
    //Log.d("Seleccionado",String.valueOf(seleccionado));

    if (seleccionado <= objetoList.size()) {
        objetoList.get(seleccionado).coordenada.set(((int) event.getX()), ((int) event.getY()));
    } else {
        // Detectr izq o der
        int pos = (int) ((event.getX() - lastPosX));
        if (pos > 0 && lastPosX != 0f) {
            //Derecha
            for (Objeto o : objetoList) {
                o.coordenada.x += pos;
            }
        } else if (lastPosX != 0f) {
            //Izq
            for (Objeto o : objetoList) {
                o.coordenada.x -= -1 * pos;
            }
        }
        lastPosX = event.getX();
    }
    if (event.getAction() == android.view.MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN) {
        Log.d("TouchTest", "Touch down");
    } else if (event.getAction() == android.view.MotionEvent.ACTION_UP) {
        Log.d("TouchTest", "Touch up");
        lastPosX = 0;
    }
    return super.onTouchEvent(event);
}

private int obtenerTocado(Point punto) {
    int out = 10;
    Log.d("Seleccionado", "Punto tocado:(" + punto.x + "," + punto.y + ")");
    for (int i = 0; i < objetoList.size(); i++) {
        Objeto o = objetoList.get(i);
        Log.d("Seleccionado", "Objeto pos: (" + o.coordenada.x + "," + o.coordenada.y + ")");
        if (punto.x - o.coordenada.x <= o.bounds[2] & punto.x - o.coordenada.x >= o.bounds[0]) {
            if (punto.y - o.coordenada.y <= o.bounds[1]) {
                if (punto.y - o.coordenada.y >= o.bounds[3]) {
                    return i;
                }
            }
        }
    }
    return out;
}
}
```

Comment: Funciona perfecto, no había caído en lo de la conversión que se pierde precisión aunque aun no llego a entender porque se quedaban quietos.

Comment: Si quieres probar, te explico. Coloca tu codigo anterior y haz lo siguiente, desplaza los cuadrados por el lado izquierdo de la pantalla y deja presionado, veras como éstos automaticamente sin hacer nada regresan a la pantalla, eso se debe a que `lastPosX` era un `int` y al asignar el valor X de event, pierde precision, ej: event-X = 29.182, lastPosX = 29, cuando comprobaba el if la resta de ambos, el resultado era 0.182, era mayor a 0, por lo que entraba en el primer if aun sin mover a la derecha. Asi que cambiando `lastPosX` a un flotante puedes hacer bien la resta sin perder precision

Comment: Solucionado eso, estaba igual el problema que estos se paraban en la pantalla, esto se debe a la comparacion de float en la programacion, para hacer una comparacion muy precisa se necesita mas que `if(x > 0` ya que pierde mucha precision, pero como tampoco necesitas, valga la redundancia, mucha precision, he optado por castear a `int` la resta de `eventX` y `lastPosX` para poder compararla bien y asi que no entre en el primer if. En resumidas cuentas, cuando se desplazaba a la izquierda con valores cercanos a 0, a veces entraba en el if de mover a la derecha por eso ocurria al hacerlo despacio

Comment: Vale, todo aclarado. No habia repasado el proceso y tenido en cuenta los decimales del float. Gracias, Un saludo